# Can I have several 'similar' database tables to reduce retrieval time

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, scalability

It is best to explain my question in terms of a concrete example.

Consider an order management application that restaurants use to receive orders from their customers. I have a table called orders which stores all of them.

Now every day the tables keep growing in size but the **amount of data accessed is constant**. Generally the restaurants are only interested in orders received in the last day or so. After 100 days, for example, 'interesting' data is only about 1/100 of the table size; after 1 year it's 1/365 and so on.

Of course, I want to keep all the old orders, but performance for applications that are only interested in current orders keeps reducing. So what is the best way to not have old data interfere with the data that is 'interesting'?

From my limited database knowledge, one solution that occurred to me was to have two identical tables - order_present and order_past - within the same database. New orders would come into 'order_present' and a cron job would transfer all processed orders older than two days to 'order_old', keeping the size of 'order_present' constant.

Is this considered an acceptable solution to deal with this problem. What other solutions exist?

Comment: You can cache the most accessed values with Memcached: http://memcached.org/ or with Redis: http://redis.io/ or any key-value in-memory database

Comment: With suitable indexing (and potentially partitioning once the table gets *really* big), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Nanocom the values being accessed keep changing, so how will caching work?

Comment: @eggyal How big is _really_ big until this starts becoming a problem? And partitioning is exactly what I'm talking about. I just didn't know it existed. But the question still remains. When is partitioning a good idea?

Comment: Well I worked on a table with over 900 000 000 rows in and the table was about 750GB. Production data at a brewery(loved that job free beer). However we still had good performance on the table due to partitioning and indexing as eggyal suggested. Archiving is a form of partitioning but can become labor intensive depending on your needs. Best is to optimize queries first. All SQL engines are extremely good at dealing with high volumes of data. If queries are running slow they probably missing a index.

Comment: @slider: How big is *really* big will depend on your hardware and configuration.  I would simply reiterate Knuth's maxim that "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*" and also the KISS principle (keep it simple, stupid): don't worry about partitioning until you notice that performance is starting to suffer - I suggest this might be some years away, by which time you may have decided to completely overhaul the system/design/server/application anyway.

Comment: @eggyal Got it. You are right, it is a couple of years away. Heck, I haven't even launched the thing yet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database servers are pretty good at handling volume. But the performance could be limited by physical hardware. If it is the IO latency that is bothering you, there are several solutions available. You really need to evaluate what fits best for your usecase.

For example:

1. you can [Partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) the table to distribute it onto multiple physical disks.
2. you can do [Sharding](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html) to put data on to different physical servers
3. you can evaluate using another [Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html) which best fits your data and application. MyISAM delivers better read performance compared to InnoDB at the cost of being less ACID compliant
4. you can use [Read Replicas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) to deligate all (most) "select" queries to replicas (slaves) of the main database servers (master)

Finally, [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) is a great resource on this topic.